# Ubercart end category listing page(before node) need to make more beautiful

Tags: drupal, ubercart

Ubercart end category listing page(before node) need to be more beautiful, so I need to add some more fields Eg: Title, image, treaser view of node description etc. is it possible?

Screenshot : http://www.ubercart.org/files/screenshot_5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck), you can add custom fields to any node type, including an Ubercart listing page.

Comment: using cck already, Pls check this link so you can understand what i want exact. http://demo.adasystemsinc.com/products/cctv-systems/cctv-cameras/dome-camera
I need to beatify this same as parent page